# Application shuts down when ever an error is occured

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-2.3

In android studio v 2.3, in logcat whenever an error is occured, error is not showing in logcat instead app shuts down and shows below log.

> D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM  I/art: System.exit called, status:
>   2 I/AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 2, cleanup skipped.

Comment: please post the error log

Comment: Something in your app is calling `System.exit()`.

Comment: Check if you have thrown an exception? (put a breakpoint on the section prior to crash and step through the code)

Comment: are you using emulator or a real device ?

Comment: Search your code for `System.exit(2)`.

Comment: Yes i was calling System.exit(2) Thank you so much.